# Requested security information is either unavailable

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

So basically we have a client whom on their Fileserver, contains a shared application which is their client management software which everyone runs. However there is one user which gets the following error when they try to run from the share, and the only thing which appears the resolve the problem (but only temporarily) is rebooting the machine.

The error is just the standard Windows cannot access this file.... but when looking at the security from their account - "requested security information is either unavailable or cannot be displayed"

But he can log in with his domain account on another machine and access it fine so evidently permissions are correct, which I've checked. Any ideas?!

Cheers!

Comment: If he logs on to another machine with his account, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Is it possible the problem system is disjoined from the domain?

Comment: Replace the user's machine with another one if he can log into any computer ( without rebooting the server ) and its not a problem.  if this effects a single user, then its a problem WITH the user's account, nothing else.